# How to add Basic Auth to Python REST API hosted on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I develop a HTTP REST API using Python flask, which is hosted on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (platform: Python 3.4). To secure the API I want to add Basic Authentication to it.

First approach is to add the Basic Auth directly in the Python application (as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/)). This requires to enable auth forwarding by adding a .conf file in the .ebextensions directory:

```
container_commands:
  01_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

Second approach is to configure the Elastic Beanstalk container by adding a .config file in the .ebextensions directory. The following configuration I have from [here](http://enrico.quora.com/How-to-protect-an-elastic-beanstalk-environment). However this is not working for me.

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/allow_override.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      <Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
      </Directory>

  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/auth.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      <Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "My Application"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
      </Directory>

  "/etc/httpd/.htpasswd":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      appuser:pw1234
```

What is the best approach to add Basic Auth to the Python API (under the condition that SSL may be added later on too) If the second one, why is the .conf file not working.

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways you can go.

Flask has an example of HTTP basic auth.
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import request, Response

from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection for users table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost/dbname')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
session = Session()

def check_auth(username, password):
    # query users table (probably want to hash the password or something)
    return session.query(Users).filter_by(username=username, password=password).first() is not None

def authenticate():
    """Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth"""
    return Response(
    'Could not verify your access level for that URL.\n'
    'You have to login with proper credentials', 401,
    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization  # checks authorization headers -> Authorization: username="me" password="12345"
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

This allows you to use @requires_auth decorator on any functions (probably just endpoints) and it will check the authorization header sent from the client. You don't have to use sqlalchemy but it's very frequently used with Flask.

Or... Auth0 has their way of authenticating through them. I don't work for them and am not trying to advertise for them; I have just used it in the past and it worked well.

https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/python

Good Luck!

Comment: I am currently using HTTP Basic Auth in Flask with enabled auth forwarding in the AEB container. However, my question is, whether this is the best practice or not.

Comment: The question isn't about how to do Basic Auth in Flask. Is about EB removing the Authorization header. None of the approaches worked for me. I still get the authorization header stripped.