# Flask-BasicAuth on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to password protect an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Flask site. I just need to be able to have the site available to people in my organization and not available to those outside of the organization, i.e. very simple password protection.

I'm using the Flask tutorial given [here](https://flask-basicauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to try to learn how to password protect the site. I'm using Amazon ELB - "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.6.5 running Python 3.4" configuration.

```
from flask import Flask                                                         
from flask_basicauth import BasicAuth                                           

app = Flask(__name__)                                                           

app.config['BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'] = 'john'                                      
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD'] = 'matrix'                                    

basic_auth = BasicAuth(app)                                                     


@app.route('/secret.html')                                                      
@basic_auth.required                                                            
def secret_view():                                                              
    return app.send_static_file('secret.html')                                  


@app.route('/not-secret.html')                                                  
def not_secret():                                                               
    return app.send_static_file('not-secret.html')                              

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
        app.run()
```

The app works just as expected locally, but it doesn't work after launching the app.

After launching the app, I receive the below error message:

```
[http2:warn] [pid 13837] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not
supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed
in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently
selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning.
Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
```

Loading either page results in error 500 in the browser.

Stuck on this one, thanks in advance for assistance.

What needs to be done in order to use `BasicAuth` on ELB in this manner?

Comment: ELB is oblivious to your auth scheme, it will see a header "Authorization: Basic XYZ" and just forward it to the instance. I'd investigate if the apache installed in your instance isn't scrubbing the header before it reaches your app.

Comment: did you try `WSGIPassAuthorization: on` as explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350574/how-to-add-basic-auth-to-python-rest-api-hosted-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk ? This has solved the issue for me